# JQuery Mobile - JavaScript Visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a page on which I'm using JQuery Mobile. I am having difficulty understanding when exactly my variables are visible. I thought that the following were loaded into the same memory space. But I get an error. Before I explain the error let me show the code:

**Page.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="myPage" data-role="page">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My App</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="content">
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
          <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="button" value="First" onclick="return button1_Click();" /></div>
          <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="button" value="Second" onclick="return button2_Click();" /></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        var currentIndex = 0;
        function button1_Click() {
          alert(myCollection.length);
        }

        function button2_Click() {

        }
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**App.js**

```
$("#myPage").live("pagecreate", function () {
});

$("#myPage").live("pagebeforeshow", function () {
});

$("#myPage").live("pageshow", function () {
  var myCollection = loadCollection();
  function loadCollection() {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

When I click the "First" button, my event handler is called. However, I receive the following error:

*ReferenceError: myCollection is not defined*

My question is how can I share variables between these two files? I'm also concerned about name collisions which is why I was hope to share the memory space in the manner I attempted below. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myCollection` is defined within the scope of a callback function and thus only exists within that callback function. It is not available outside that scope.  If you want it available globally, you have to define it as a global variable, outside of a function scope.

Your code in app.js also should be surrounded with `$(document).ready()` because you're trying to reference the DOM before it exists.